# gulp-minify-css-names producing non-modified files

Tags: html, css, node.js, npm, gulp

I am looking for long time for a solution that will help me automate renaming/minifying class names in **HTML, JS, CSS** files altogether across whole project in gulp.

There are mane css + js only solutions. The one that works for all 3 types of source files is gulp-minify-css-names. But after installing it and creating gulp task similar to example on nmp site - i can't get it to work.

It produces non-modified css file(same for html and js).

The code of task

```js
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var gulpMinifyCssNames = require('gulp-minify-css-names');

    gulp.task('minify-css-names', function() {
        return gulp.src(['src/*.css'])
            .pipe(gulpMinifyCssNames())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
    });
```

project page - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css-names

Why it isnt working ?

I have opened source code of gulp-minify-css-names in my node_modules folder and found it extremely small of a size: **78 lines total**

Comment: That project is forked from this one: https://github.com/Connormiha/gulp-minify-cssnames - also, did you use a prefix or a postfix in your class names?  The replacer only works with prefixed or postfixed names. The default is '--s--'.

Answer (score 0):

This lib requires that you prefix/append your css names. In their example, they have the following css:

```
.-pre-menu-post- {color: red;}
.-pre-menu_top-post- {color: black;}
.-pre-menu_item-post- {color: green;}
.-pre-menu_item_active-post- {color: blue;}
.-pre-menu_item_active-post-::before {content: 'active'}
```

where `-pre-` is the default prefix and `-post-` is the default suffix.

[Justification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css-names#why-need-a-prefixappend):

> Why need a prefix/append?
> This plugin match by RegExp in all
> file/stream content. This will reduce the likelihood of wrong
> replacement.